# Add relation between two existing/filled tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

A while back when I was creating a database containing two tables (`Topics` and `Categories` where every topic is categorized) I didn't bother how to properly model the relation between these two tables because I was very unexperienced with MySQL and databases in general.

My simple approach was to just insert the category's name in the `Category` column of the `Topics` table.

Now that I have to change some category names I regret this decision because beside just changing it I have to assimilate all relevant entries in the `Topics` table. That's easily done with the correct MySQL statements but it's a very messy solution.

So I wonder if it's still possible to add the intended relation to the existing tables. So far I've tried some approaches I found in similar topics but most were regarding other problems. It might help that the `Topics` category column and the `Categories` name column share the same values: the name of the category.

Topics:

```
+----+------+----------+------+
| Id | Name | Category | Date |
+----+------+----------+------+
```

Categories:

```
+------+-------------+
| Name | Description |
+------+-------------+
```

I'm thankful for every solution or tip be it for the command line or phpmyadmin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to Categories:

```
enter code here`ALTER TABLE `categories` ADD `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);
```

Add a Category ID to Topics:

```
ALTER TABLE `topics` ADD `Category_Id` INT NOT NULL AFTER `Name`;
```

Then update the Category ID based on Category:

```
UPDATE `topics`, `categories` SET `topics`.`Category_Id` = `categories`.`Id` WHERE `topics`.`Category` = `categories`.`Name`
```

After you verify everything is good, change any code referencing `topics`.`Category` with a JOIN to connect the tables and use `categories`.`Name` instead and then remove the `categories`.`Name` field.